# Writing Parquet file that has been transformed to CSV format takes 4+ hours

Tags: python, scala, csv, apache-spark, bigdata

I recently started a new job where I have to do data manipulation on a very large data set (207 Billion rows). The basic premise of the spark code has to:

Import all parquet files from an Azure Data Lake directory . We will call this file "Big File".

Load in a csv file called "Products" that contains a list of products, and filter the "Big File" where the products exist in both sets. Ex: If "database" exists in the products csv then keep the record in Big file, otherwise discard the record from "Big File".

Load in a region mapping csv file that appends addition geographical data to the "Big File". Ex: If "Big File" country column has Japan as the country, then the region mapping csv appends APJ as the region and JP as the country code.

Once the above filters are done I have to filter for a particular region like APJ and then drop duplicates based on all the columns.

The last step would be to export this data frame to Azure Data Lake as a CSV file. Ideally I would like this output to be 1 file instead of multiple CSV files.

When I run this job, it takes at least 4 hours to complete.

I've tried to do my own research and tried the following to speed up the job:

1. Broadcasting the smaller region mapping csv to do the join with "Big File"
2. Implying the schema when reading in the "Big File".
3. Persisting and caching the "Big File" once it is read in.
4. Rewrite using spark sql but performance didn't change.
5. Tried using coalesce,

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("path")
```

6. Tried using repartition and partition by

```
DF.repartition(100, $"country").write.option("header", "true").partitionBy("country").mode("overwrite").csv("path")
```

Here's some code snippets if that helps:

````
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val six_months_prior = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(LocalDateTime.now.minusMonths(6))

val Big_File = spark.read.format("parquet").

load("Big_File_Path").

selectExpr("company_name as Company_Name",

"domain as URL",

"company_size as Company_Size",

"industry as Industry",

"domain_origin as Country",

"topic as Topic",

"record_date as Record_Date").filter(!($"Company_Name"==="") && ($"Record_Date" >= six_months_prior))

val Topics = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("azure path"). rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect().toList

val Bombora_Intent = Bombora_Intent.filter(($"Topic".isin(Topics:_*)))

val Region_Mapping = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", true).load("Region_Path")

val df = Bombora_Intent.join(broadcast(Region_Mapping), Seq("Country")).select("Company_Name", "URL", "Company_Size", "Industry","Record_Date", "Region", "Country", "Country_Code")

val new_df = Bombora_Intent_SAP_Topics.filter($"Region" === "APJ").distinct()

new_df.write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv("azure_path")```
````

physical plan:

[image: Click here an img of the physical plan:]

Comment: what  is your spark-submit configuration